# Prove that if b is an undefined dot product, then there is a base of time vectors, another of light vectors, and another of space vectors

Tags: geometry, analysis

Prove that if b is an undefined dot product, then there is a base of time vectors, another of light vectors, and another of space vectors.
Taking into account that:

1. Luminous implies $ b (v, v) = 0 $
2. Time implies $ b (v, v) <0 $
3. Spatially implies $ b (v, v)> 0 $

I think that one should start with the basis of orthonormal vectors. Since this is always possible because by definition a dot product is always non-degenerate. Then, from that orthonormal basis, it would be possible to build the required bases. But I wouldn't know how to do it